# shotwell migrate 0.12.3 to 0.28.4

Tags: shotwell

I'm replacing an old computer that has Shotwell 0.12.3 with a new one that has 0.28.4.  Can I simply copy .shotwell from the old to .local/share/shotwell, as well as the actual picture directory, of course?

Comment: What OS/release are you running?   Shotwell 0.12.3 is not used by any supported release of Ubuntu.  Most later releases of programs can cope with the older versions files (updating those changes), but if your releases differ to much it may not cope as well (if changes clash; coders assume the nearer older release usually so checking that is on you; your release details are what I'd use to start evaluation..)  If it's to a new computer, I'd just try it and see, if you have problems roll back to before and think of something else if you don't want to do the homework if evaluating changes..

Comment: Going from Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae Debian 3.2.89-1 to Linux 5.3.0-28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu.  You're right.  I'll just try it.  If that doesn't work, does Shotwell have an export that includes all the metadata?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that metadata in version 0.12.3 are compatible with the newer versions. To clarify, I copied `~/.shotwell` from my old computer running **Shotwell 0.12.3** to `~/.local/share` (that is, to `~/.local/share/shotwell`) on my new computer running **Shotwell 0.28.4**.  I see no sign of any metadata being lost in the process.

Comment: That is good to know.